# Return only numbers from a column with numbers and text

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Hello again stackoverflow. My question should be fairly simple; How do you return a series of numbers from a mixed column of numbers and text?

I have something analogous to;

```
Text
5
Text
1
Text
Text
4
```

What I want from this, in another worksheet, is;

```
5
1
0     (if two rows of text are next to each other, I'd like to return 0)
4
```

Thanks for any assistance.

This spreadsheet lists containers and their contents. The first text in the series is an identifying marker. The second is how many items are in the container, the third is a smaller container within the first (I don't care how many items are in that one, just if it is present or not).

```
Column A  (Sheet1)
Box
5
Bag
Box
1
Bag
Box
Bag
Box
4
Bag
```

The input is copy/pasted from a program and cannot be altered. What I want to do is, on another spreadsheet, say; Box has 5 pieces, 1 bag. Represented as;

```
Row 1 (Sheet2)
 Box 5 1
```

Comment: What if three rows of text are together?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I can think of doing this would be to use the column NEXT to this column and have the following formula (assuming your data starts in cell A1):

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(A1),A1,IF(NOT(ISNUMBER(A2)),0,""))
```

Then drag that formula down the length of your "helper column" and then filter it for non-blanks.

Hope this is a good enough answer for what you're trying to achieve...

Comment: This is close, it returns "0" for all text though, which doesn't work for my purposes. I get an output of; 0 5 0 1 0 0 4, where I'm looking for the above. I tried something similar to this and got the same result :(. Thanks Though.

Comment: Then it leaves blank cells for the text, and in some instances, I need that output as 0. My end goal is to turn the first column listed into the second. I will amend my first post with a third example to clarify.

Comment: Please still re-clarify your question... I'm not sure I understand what output you want and, therefore, it's really hard to answer correctly....

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Boxes_and_stuff()

Dim j As Byte
Dim ThisPage As Worksheet, TargetPage As Worksheet
Dim NewBook As Workbook

Set ThisPage = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
Set NewBook = Workbooks.Add   ' or you can address an existing file with workbooks.open(filename)
Set TargetPage = NewBook.Worksheets(1) ' you can also decide the sheet where you want to write your values (here by default is the first excel's "tab")

j = 1 ' cells' scanner

Do Until IsEmpty(ThisPage.Cells(j, 1))

    If ThisPage.Cells(j, 1).Text = "Box" Then   
    ' if "Box" is found scan cell below to find bags or numbers

            If ThisPage.Cells(j + 1, 1).Text = "Bag" Then TargetPage.Cells(1 + j, 1) = "Box 0 1" ' if only a bag is found
            If ThisPage.Cells(j + 1, 1).Text = "Box" Then TargetPage.Cells(1 + j, 1) = "Box 0 0" ' if nothing is inside a box and another box comes next (I'm assuming that "0" items will never show)

            If IsNumeric(ThisPage.Cells(j + 1, 1)) Then ' if a number shows...

                If (ThisPage.Cells(j + 2, 1)).text = "Bag" then '... the next can be bag
                    TargetPage.Cells(1 + j, 1) = "Box " & ThisPage.Cells(j + 1, 1) & " 1"
                Else '...or not
                    TargetPage.Cells(1 + j, 1) = "Box " & ThisPage.Cells(j + 1, 1) & " 0"
                End If

            End If

    End If

j = j + 1

Loop

End Sub
```